Need an inductive predicate over distinct pairs of list elements
I'm trying to express a symmetric but non-reflexive relation over pairs of distinct list elements. ForallPairs will include the pair (x,x), ForallOrdPairs is designed for non-symmetric relations. Before I define my own-- is there an appropriate inductive predicate I'm missing?
Update: In my particular case, I have lists of pairs of nats. The relation I wish to state is: for any two list elements (i1,j1) and (i2,j2), i1<>i2/\j1<>j2. So, e.g., a list like [(1,1),(1,1),(2,3)] would not satisfy this predicate.

ForallPairs (fun x y => x <> y → R x y)?

lol... a man after my own heart. The thing is, in my particular case, I wish to rule-out duplicates. Let me update the question.

That relation is symmetric, so you can use ForallPairsOrd.
